# SQL Server "Maximum Server Memory" - seems to have no effect on Virtual Size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

On 32 bit windows xp, sql server express, I set SQL Server "Maximum Server Memory" to 200 MB, but as soon as I start it, in Sysinternals Process Explorer I still see Virtual Size consumed of 1.5 GB.

Now I know this is no big deal if the Virtual Size is small, but when other applications max out the physical memory (Internet Explorer *cough*), I then get windows "virtual memory too small" errors, so then I think it does become a problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behavior by design, per http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=377495.  The memory is reserved, but not committed.